# haxelib selfupdate won't work

Tags: haxe, haxelib

Whenever I run haxelib selfupdate I get the following error:

Error writing file /usr/bin/haxelib. Please ensure you have write permissions. 
  [file_open,/usr/bin/haxelib]

I tried to change the owner and group of /usr /usr/bin and /usr/bin/haxelib to my own user and group to no use. I get the same error :/

If I try to run haxelib as administrator, it requires me to make a new haxelib setup (I guess it is one setup per user). Once I did the setup and ran sudo haxelib selfupdate I got the folloing error:

Error compiling haxelib client: Standard library not found

I tried to found more resources on how haxelib works and is organized to try to solve this issue but I couldn't. Could anyone explain me what I am missing? I know it is very silly but I can't get it to word.

Comment: I'm not sure but this may be indeed an issue with the `haxelib` utility itself and/or the way Haxe is installed on Linux. I can confirm the problem, but have no solution either.

Comment: It seems that the issue is already being discussed:
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxelib/issues/189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [commit](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxelib/commit/02a5fec67dda83748696f5bb6ee30ead87104b3c) the command `haxelib selfupdate` is deprecated and will be removed in future. [There more changes](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxelib/blob/master/CHANGES.md).

Use `haxelib --global update haxelib` instead.